# TFS build agent Version 2.xxx.x features

Tags: build-agent, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

i tried searching online what are the new features in upgrading TFS Build agent V1 to V2? any document link please? The only place i see some are [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/releases)

Comment: It's not a matter of features, it's a matter of compatibility. You have to do it.

Comment: May be can i ask Whats new in V2? some high level topics

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the docs you're after. What's the goal you're trying to reach?

Comment: Every time we upgrade to new version we need to document what has been updated and document atlease few enhancements what is in the new version along with reference to web links. this is basically any dev just opens what new feature has been added to the upgrade and will check if needed any improvements with the internal purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The V2 agent has a number of changes:

- It splits the agent from the execution engine, making it easier to version tasks and to run the same process locally as well as on the server (if you're a task developer)
- It adds the PowerShell3 Handler, which replaces the older PowerShell handler.
- It adds the Node handler (depending on which 1.x version you were on)
- It is fully cross platform and works on mac, linux and windows using the same core agent

These combined enable:

- Support for the latest tasks that depend on the PowerShell3 SDK and the latest Node SDK
- Adds support for multiple agent phase

The old PowerShell SDK is considered deprecated and no new tasks are developed for it. To use the latest features and to use the latest versions of Visual Studio, the PowerShell3 and Node task handlers are required.

Comment: Thank you so much. Any Microsoft document to go over please. i need to document as a task so trying to get as much as i can.

Comment: There isn't much else. The 1.x agent is deprecated, doesn't ship with TFS2018 anymore and is a required upgrade for many of the tasks that ship with newer versions of TFS. There is no exact doc that specifies this, The vsts-tasks github gives an indication which tasks need the 2.x agent: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/search?l=JSON&q=minimumAgentVersion